# DateTime.DaysInMonth returns 29 for feb. 2000?

Tags: c#, datetime

i think i have a little issue, but i'm not sure, because it's either i am wrong or .Net is wrong, and usually it is not .Net :)

but in my testscenario i did this:

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(2000,2)
```

and it returned 29.

But as far as i know 400 years (0,400,800,1200 etc.) are not leap years?

Comment: And you're looking at it from the future. Oh, the mess this caused at the time...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.NET is correct: years that are divisible by **100** aren't leap years, unless they are also divisible by **400**.

Comment: Yep, the Y2.1 k problem is going to catch a lot of people by surprise.